# getting selected value of the drop down list(<select> tag) in rest web services

Tags: java, html, rest

I am developing the web service using REST.
I have front end which has HTML 5. I have select tag which provides the option to user for department selection. Once department is selected and `SUBMIT` button is clicked , that value is to be passed to Web Service which in turn store it in database.

`I have called web service in action attribute of the form.`

I have added the `<select>` tag in the form to send all data as POST and `@FormParam(...)` to retrieve these parameter at web service.
How should I get these selected value in web service. Is there anything like getParameter("id") as in jsp, or getElementbyID("id").selectedIndex as in javascript()?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your FormParams in JAXRS based web service method like this:

```
public Response myWebServiceMethod(@FormDataParam("myFormParam") String myFormParam,
            @FormDataParam("myFormParam2") String myFormParam)
```

Comment: In @FormDataParam("myFormParam"), myFormParam is the name of the tag. I have selcet tag so i want the selected value out of that. How should I get that one? If I have text or password as input then i can directly access them by FormParam.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use jQuery? Because you can make an ajax call to your service. With jQuery you can get de id value of the selected item in the combo when the user click your button, then you only need to call the service to send this value.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: But in web service, by what ID should I access it. Like the @FormParam values as I want sent it by POST. In jquery I can use somrthing like $.post(...) so ID will remain same as that of form. Can I change that one